# EF Core: Only part of the model is saved to the database

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I try to use EF core, but only a part of my model is saved to the database.

This is my model:

```
public class EngineType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public long CarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EngineType Engine { get; set; }
}
```

The CarId and the Name is saved, but not the EngineType.

This is the test I use, but `actual.Engine` is always null:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void WhenIAddAndSaveANewCarThenItIsAddedToDB()
    {
        using var target = new EFCoreExampleContext();
        using var concurrentContext = new EFCoreExampleContext();
        var expected = new Car() {CarId = 0815, Name = "Isetta", Engine = new EngineType() { Name = "2Takt" }};

        target.Cars.Add(expected);
        target.SaveChanges();
        var actual = concurrentContext.Cars.Single();

        Assert.AreEqual(1, concurrentContext.Cars.Count());
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual.Engine);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

My Context looks like this:

```
public class EFCoreExampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Add_writes_to_database");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EngineType>(
            d =>
            {
                d.HasKey(e => e.Name);
                d.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired();
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<EngineType>(
            d =>
            {
                d.HasKey(e => e.Name);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>(
           d =>
           {
               d.HasKey(e => e.CarId);
               d.Property<DateTime>("LastChanged").IsRowVersion().ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
               d.Property<string>("EngineForeignKey");
               d.HasOne(e => e.Engine)
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("EngineForeignKey")
                        .IsRequired();
           });
    }
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong (or which existing topic answers this question - I even didn't have the right search words to find it).

Thanks!

Comment: `Cars.Single()`? What makes you think that is going to pull the correct car? Try `var actual = concurrentContext.Cars.Where(x => x.Id == expexted.Id).Single();`

Comment: Because it is only one car in the db... Thanks for looking at the code @mxmissile !

Comment: Where are you wiping the db? Test Methods should be designed to be run lots of times, over and over.

Comment: Hi @mxmissile, I don't need to wipe the db as it is a in-memory db (for the tests), and there is an Assert in the test that exactly one item is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no issue with saving. Entity Framework does not do eager loading by default. So you have to explicitly include any navigational properties that should be in result. Try this when you are fetching actual,

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var actual = concurrentContext.Cars.Include(c => c.Engine).Single();
```